# Separate string with HTML tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str = '<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph</p>
```

I have a string `str`
I want to separate `h1` and `p` text.

Result:

```
var h = 'Header'
var p = 'Paragraph'
```

Is there any shortcut way?
I tried it with for loop.

Comment: `$.parseHTML( str )` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Comment: A way of doing would be to use the .match method with a regex. and ot catch the element between the diffrents tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go, without String manipulation:

```js
const str = '<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph</p>'
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
const [h, p] = [...div.children].map(el=>el.textContent);

console.log(h, p);
```

Or even cleaner, using the **experimental** [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API:

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph</p>', 'text/html');
const [h, p] = [...doc.body.children].map(el=>el.textContent);

console.log(h, p);
```

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
var str = '<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph</p>'
var h = $.parseHTML( str )[0].innerText
var p = $.parseHTML( str )[1].innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try regex:

```js
var str = '<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph</p>';
var result = str.match(/<([\w]+)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/([\w]+)[^>]*>/g).map(function(val){
    var pre = val.split('>')[1];
    return pre.substr(0, pre.lastIndexOf('<'));
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Regex and html-markup don't mix very well. In my experience, your regex will get more and more complicated as you come across all of the what is called by the name of HTML